# Angular $scope $watch on service function return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a service for my websocket connection and this service returns in a function the actual state whether the client is actual connected or not.
I've simplified my code and these snippets are a small example of my problem:

```
myApp.factory('Websocket', function() {
    //the status boolean whether connected or not
    var bool = true;

    //small mock for the status change
    setInterval(function() {
        bool = !bool;
    }, 1000);

    //i've made the value of the status variable accessable in a function or the variable itself
    return {
        status: function() {
            return bool;   
        },
        var: bool
    }
});
```

Now i tried to apply the status value to my scope in the controller:

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function(Websocket, $scope) {
   //method 1
   $scope.status = Websocket.status();

   //method 2
   $scope.$watch(function() {
     return Websocket.status();
   }, function(newVal) {
     $scope.status = newVal;
   });
});
```

...but both methods don't work and don't update the $scope variable for this html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      method1: {{status}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVjaBa?editors=101

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that any "external" change to data watched by Angular has to call `scope.$apply()` for the watchers to update (here the watchers are the UI from the `{{status}}` expression). In the codepen the solution is simple: Make the service depend on the `$rootScope` and call `$rootScope.$apply()` in the interval function:

```
myApp.factory('Websocket', function($rootScope) {
    ...
    setInterval(function() {
        bool = !bool;
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }, 1000);
    ...
});
```

Something similar has to be done with the real service, key concepts being: (1) you have to call `$apply()` and (2) having no access to a specific scope, just use the `$rootScope`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd go with $rootScope.$digest right off the bat instead of $apply - as all you're doing is jumping through a try/catch statement to reach the same result. [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.16/src/ng/rootScope.js#L886). Not really costly but, there's no real reason for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as Nikos mentioned: you are changing the variable's value outside of the digest loop, so angular is not following the changes.

Using `$scope.$apply` is one option, but in this case I would prefer using [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `setInterval`.

```
myApp.factory('Websocket', function($interval) {
  var bool = true;
  $interval(function() {
    bool = !bool;
  }, 1000);

  return {
    status: function() {
        return bool;   
    },
    var: bool
  }
});
```

See it working [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYqpRr?editors=101).

Comment: Thanks for your help!